# SQL across two tables is showing duplicate records

Tags: sql

Using this SQL:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM shop_products p, shop_product_attributes c 
WHERE c.type = 'category' AND p.sequence = c.value AND c.value = '1'
```

It's showing the same record twice.

it should be showing rows from `shop_products where shop_products.sequence` is in `shop_product_attributes.product_seq` and `shop_product_attributes.value` is `'1'`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include sample data from both tables and the output you're trying to obtain. Also, please add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as there are syntax differences between them. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your descrption shop products have many attributes.  and it appears at least one product in shop_product_Attributes with a type of c  and a value of 1 has more than 1 record.  you can add a "Distinct' to your select to resolve the problem; but if duplicate records shouldn't exist for the same type, and value, you may want to add a unique constraint.

Comment: Your query doesn't match your last sentence, you talk about `product_seq`, but join on `c.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM shop_products s
where s.sequence 
in(select distinct product_seq from shop_product_attributes where type = 'category' and value=1)
```

Comment: What happened to category?

Comment: Oops missed it initially. Edited the query now.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-select is useless

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't match your last sentence, you talk about `product_seq`, but join on `c.value`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM shop_products p JOIN shop_product_attributes c 
  ON p.sequence = c.product_seq 
WHERE c.type = 'category' 
  AND c.value = '1'
```